# How to use ActiveModel::Lint::Tests in Rspec

Tags: rspec, activemodel, lint

For default Rails, you can add so called [`ActiveModel::Lint::Tests`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Lint/Tests.html) to see if your models adhere to parts of the ActiveModel.

I would like to call these, or an equivalent thereof in my Rspec tests.

- I don't want to test the exact behaviour: the lint tests only spec that a certain interface exists. I want to only spec that the interface exists.
- I rather not [test too close implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9131586/73673). Merely testing that a module is included is not really the same as testing an interface exists.

Is there a trick to run and include the Rails core `ActiveModel::Lint::Tests` in rspec examples? Are there alternatives, specially built for Rspec that run such lint-tests?

**Some background**:

I am building models that don't inherit from `Activerecord::Base`, but instead act as factories or state-machines. In Rails also known as Service-Objects. These should feel like ActiveModels for the user. Things like

```
@services << CompositeService.new(name: 'foo', children: [{ name: 'bar' }])
render @services
```

should be possible. Such a `CompositeService` should then, have activemodel naming, partial paths, caching-ids and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing a gem that provides `ActiveModel`-compliant models and using RSpec 3.x.

To get the lint tests, I added `activemodel` as a development dependency.  That also brings in `ActiveSupport` and with it `Minitest`.  I figured I could use something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmitriy-kiriyenko/1892874) as I have in the past, but ran into an [issue](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/450) trying to get the tests to use `Minitest`'s `assert`.

I ended up throwing this together (credit to the gist's author) and putting it into `spec/support`:

```
require 'active_model/lint'
require 'minitest'

RSpec.shared_examples_for ActiveModel do
  include ActiveModel::Lint::Tests
  include Minitest::Assertions

  alias_method :model, :subject

  attr_accessor :assertions

  before(:each) { self.assertions = 0 }

  ActiveModel::Lint::Tests.public_instance_methods.map(&:to_s).grep(/^test/).each do |m|
    it(m.sub 'test_', 'responds to ') { send m }
  end
end
```

This seems to be working so far, I get error messages like this:

```
Failure/Error: it(m.sub 'test_', 'responds to ') { send m }
Minitest::Assertion:
 The model should respond to to_key
```

It's not ideal, but it's fine with me for now.  The lint tests are so simple
that it would be pretty trivial to implement a shared example from scratch
(see [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/lint.rb)), but this way I can just rely on the gem to keep the tests up-to-date.